# Gerrit branch access modification through command line

Tags: git, gerrit

I would like to change the access rule for the deactivated branches on gerrit from "ALLOW" to "DENY".. do we have any command line options available for it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit access rights through the Git protocol using the `refs/meta/config` pseudo-branch. See the [docs](https://gerrit-documentation.storage.googleapis.com/Documentation/2.8.2/config-project-config.html).

You checkout that branch, modify the `project.config` and push back to the Gerrit server. That's how you can automate this.